# Prompt User to input Integers between 30 and 100, press 0 to exit from loop, When user presses 0, display message 'press spacebar'

Tags: mit-scratch

- Create a list called Numbers
- Prompt the user to enter Integer number between (30-100)numbers to
  the list
- Keep asking the user to enter the numbers until he enter 0 to exit
  from the loop Once the user press 0 “Display a message for the user
  to “press a space bar” to print all numbers above 50
- Once you print and all, then display a message said “Thank you ”

Now I have written the code, but it doesn't work after i press space bar

[image: Click here to see image of what i have so far]

Answer (score 0):

So you forgot to increment the new variable, and that loop that says the numbers actually loops 3 times instead of 4 on a 4-item list. So here is the working code:[CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdqAd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a if-loop instead of a wait for space key...

Answer (score 0):

There are three errors in the code:

1. Showing numbers should be outside `repeat until answer = 0`.
2. At the beginning `NewVariable` must be set to 1, not 0.
3. `NewVariable` must be incremented by one during showing numbers.

Here is corrected script.

[image]